# Auto refresh scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have two functions that work when I first enter them.  However, if I reopen the file, they do not run and leave a "Loading..." message in the cell.  Cutting and re-pasting fixes this, but I have to do this a lot.

I added an onOpen function as suggested, but this can leave me with a #ERROR! Too many script running on this Google account.

I refer to the data in this cell from another Sheet using a =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/MYSHEET", "Sheet1!CELL")
but often get a #NAME? appear in the cell.

```
function getFileUrl() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var url = '';
  url += ss.getUrl();
  url += '#gid=';
  url += ss.getSheetId(); 
  return url;
}

function getFileName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return ss.getName();
}  

function onOpen(e) {
  getFileUrl()
  getFileName()
}
```

Comment: Try not using them as custom functions

Comment: Do you know other mechanisms do the same thing?

Comment: Custom functions have many restrictions I hardly ever use them

Answer (score 0):

We would need more information regarding your functions but it appears that you are hitting quotas for Google Services. All the details can be found here:

[Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

You basically have two solutions:

- Upgrade to a google workspace account. Depending on the type of threshold your are hitting you should get from 2 to 10 times more requests.
- The cheaper and in my opinion better option is to find a way to reduce the load of your functions. Can you break them down so that some parts of your code run on every open while others only run once a day or so?

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, I am a teacher and give each student a spreadsheet that pulls data (links to lesson plans) from a master sheet.  The master sheet pulls data back so I can see students' responses.
I need to reference filenames and addresses.  The functions extract the students name from the filename and extracting the address make it easier to reference.  I could manually enter this, but I created a template to automate the process.
Do you think that I have too many student files?  I could delete former students' files.
However, I was getting refresh issues years ago before the account limit error.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. If I understand correctly then the code you posted is ran multiple times to gather all the information for each student. In my opinion a more elegant solution would be to insert a trigger in each students document to send the information to your master file. You can set the trigger to onChange, that way your code will only be triggered every time there is a change in the data. Don't hesitate to reply to this if my solution isn't clear enough.